# Why is "boost::function = boost::bind(...)" creating 13 temporaries?

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

I have some pretty basic test code. I have a class that just logs all operations on it. I bound it to a `boost::function` object like this:

```
    void Function(const Foo&)
    {
        printf("Function invoked\n");
    }

    // ...

    boost::function<void(void)> func;
    {
        Foo f;
        printf("\nConstructing function\n");
        func = boost::bind(&Function, f);
        printf("Construction complete\n\n");
    }
```

I expect that the function object contains a copy of `f`. So creating at least one copy is mandatory. However, I find that I get **13** temporaries. Output is:

```
Constructing function
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Foo::~Foo
Construction complete
```

I can't use `ref` or `cref` because I do need it to make a copy of the object. Am I doing something horribly wrong? Or do I need to use a wrapper (like `boost::shared_ptr`) to avoid an absurd number of copies?

Full code and problem demonstration can be found [on Codepad](http://codepad.org/DbOAjT2H).

Comment: I'd be interested to see what `std::bind` does.

Comment: Is this in debug or release?

Comment: @NicolBolas Just compiling with `g++`, no special flags or options except `-O2`. Tried with and without c++11, no difference.

Comment: @chris: With `std::function` and `std::bind`, only [two temporaries](http://ideone.com/1aZ3VF) are created.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Same with VC2012.

Comment: I suspect `boost::bind` has not been upgraded for C++11.

Comment: in my case boost::bind makes 14 copies and boost::function + std::bind makes 10 (gcc 4.7.2 -std=c++11 -O2). So it has to do with boost::function and boost::bind, not just boost::bind

Comment: I just had the same case and I was shocked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494516/boostbind-boostfunction-number-of-copies-of-value-passed-arguments . Have you tried using `std::function`? The performance is faaaar better (at least the copies are a lot fewer). +1 from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the "func = " assignment part the number of copies are lowered to 4 which is quite better than 13.

```
template <class F>
void callF(F fun)
{
}
callF(boost::bind(&func, fl));
```

So the solution is simple - don't use boost::function

Comment: `boost::thread(boost::bind(&Function, q));` gives me 7 temporaries.

Comment: `i.post(boost::bind(&Function, q));` gives 6 temporaries.

Comment: hum, yes, in such case I think you were right to consider a shared_ptr if the object you are posting is not small enough to be faster passed by value or if you do not need too many of them. Test performance.

Comment: I think you are right, the solution is to avoid `boost::function` if it all possible. If you can't, understand the costs. (Or go to c++11x)