# Why does this ASIO example use members variables to pass state rather than using bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In the [ASIO HTTP Server 3 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) there is code like this:

```
void server::start_accept()
{
  new_connection_.reset(new connection(io_service_, request_handler_));
  acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection_->socket(),
      boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
  if (!e)
  {
    new_connection_->start();
  }

  start_accept();
}
```

Essentially, `new_connection_` is a member of the `server` class and is used to pass a connection from `start_accept` to `handle_accept`. Now, I'm curious as to why `new_connection_` is implemented as a member variable.

Wouldn't it also work to pass the connection using `bind` instead of a member variable? Like this:

```
void server::start_accept()
{
  std::shared_ptr<connection> new_connection(new connection(io_service_, request_handler_));
  acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection_->socket(),
      boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error),
        new_connection);
}

void server::handle_accept(boost::system::error_code const& error, std::shared_ptr<connection> new_connection)
{
  if (!error) {
    new_connection->start();
  }
  start_accept();
}
```

If so, why does the example use member variables? Is it to avoid the copying involved?

(note: I'm not comfortable with ASIO yet and so there may be a fundamental misconception here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the socket variable inside a function created with `std::bind` is more or less the same as retaining it as a member variable in the [`http::server3::server`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/server.cpp) class. Using `bind` will [create temporaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617835/why-is-boostfunction-boostbind-creating-13-temporaries) whereas using the member variable will not. I don't think that is a big concern here as the `std::shared_ptr` is not terribly expensive to copy nor is this code path in the example a performance critical section.

When writing my own applications I find myself using both techniques. If the asynchronous call chain is very long I will typical retain the variables as members to simplify the handler's function signatures and prevent code repetition. For shorter call chains, keeping the state variables in the functor created from bind is a bit easier to understand the code's logic.

Comment: I often use both techniques as well, and follow the same approach as Sam.  Additionally, if a type if expensive to copy or the variable is used in multiple chains, then I prefer to use a member variable regardless of the length or simplicity of the individual call chains.

Comment: Is it a bug to 'use a class member variable'? Because if there is second client connect to the server before calling the server::handle_accept of first client, it will change the value of 'member variable new_connection_' of first client. I am new to boost asio. Maybe I am wrong.