# What are the advantages or disadvantages to using a stored boost::function vs boost::bind with boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have inherited some boost::asio code that takes advantage of the asynchronous methods to read/write data with some socket. Currently the code uses boost::bind for the Read/Write Handlers to class member functions like this:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(&in_data.header.packet_size, 1), boost::bind(&SocketIO::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

I would like to change the code to use a stored version of the bind using boost::function but I am unclear if there are any advantages or disadvantages to doing this. I would think that not recreating the bind continuously would reduce object allocations.  However the boost documentation for async_receive ([Listed Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive/overload1.html)) states "Copies will be made of the handler as required". I am unsure of what conditions would require a copy to be made or not.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is unspecified as to the conditions that will cause a handler to be copied.  When move semantics are not available, copies will be made in a few locations within Boost.Asio.  When move semantics are available, and the handler is not an `rvalue`, then I believe a single copy is made and then moved within Boost.Asio.

Answer (score 0):

Bind can actually be fairly efficient, as it can operate without ever going to the heap.  It simply copies your variables and placeholders to an internal structure on the stack, and returns that.  The resulting type is quite complicated, but you don't usually need to see any of that.

If you were to store this in a `boost::function`, this would require some sort of heap allocation.  This, in theory would only happen once, but in this case, it's not practical.

The second argument to your `bind` call is `shared_from_this()`.  This is a great way to make sure that your object isn't destroyed before all of its handlers are invoked, since ASIO will retain a shared_ptr to your object.  The issue is that if you were to store the result of `bind` in a `boost::function`, you would also store the shared pointer.  This would result in there always being a shared_ptr to your object, preventing proper destruction of your object.

Comment: One point to consider is the amount of [argument copies made by `boost::function`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14617835/1053968).  Additionally, one may want to be cautious with performing type erasure to reduce the amount of functors created, as it will prevent Boost.Asio from invoking the proper `asio_handler_*` hooks.  This should not be a problem with `boost::bind()`, but it will affect handlers returned from `strand.wrap()`.